# Stop Nextjs 13 from caching Firebase result/call

Tags: firebase, api, caching, next.js

i have this api route:

`app/api/notes/route.js`

```
import db from "@/utils/firebaseDB"
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

export const GET = async (request) => {
    let posts = []

    try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Notes"));
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            const postData = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
            posts.push(postData);
        });

        return new Response(JSON.stringify(posts), { status: 200 })
    } catch (error) {
        return new Response("Failed to fetch all data", { status: 500 })
    }
}
```

After building the project the result becomes static or cached.. So, I need a way to force the `revalidate` after a certain period.

Using `fetch` the solution is to use `fetch('https://...', { next: { revalidate: 60 } });`
but with `getDocs` I don't know.

Thank you

Comment: After solving the problem I saw your comment.. yes  "export const revalidate = 60" fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by adding `export const revalidate = 60;` I have resolved the issue.

**More info:** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/revalidating#background-revalidation

Comment: In the same file? I mean where the function is defined or where is it used?

Comment: in the link there is examples